# Unable to use bash script to remove files from git history

Tags: git, bash, sh, git-bash

I have a problem with this bash script I am writing. I am trying to apply step 3 of [this procedure from Github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) to remove all files in our repositories history from our git history. For example, if .gitignore ignores .txt, I want to remove all .txt from the history. And so on for each .gitignore line.

I am able to use a wildcard in the example file. So I can run the following to remove all .txt files:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.txt' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

So I tried to make a bash script to do the same.

I made a simple .gitignore file to test this with, as following:

```
#foo
*.txt
*.docx
```

My shell script looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

s1="#"
str1="'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch "
str2="'"

cat .gitignore | while read line
do
    if [[ $line == *"$s1"* ]]
    then
        echo #skip
    else
        str3=$str1$line$str2
        git filter-branch --force --index-filter $str3 --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
    fi
done
```

However, this results in the following output:

```
fatal: bad revision 'rm'
fatal: bad revision 'rm'
```

(Once for each line of the .gitignore file)

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Quote your variables!

Comment: You can't put complex commands in a string. Don't try. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 Especially you can't get quotes to work out correctly.

Comment: The command I am using has single quotes in it. When I just tried to run the command and add $line to it, the resulting command being run included 'git rm --cached --ignore unmatch $line' instead of containing the contents of $line.

Comment: Variables don't expand in single quotes.

Comment: Etan, is there a way to make it expand in single quotes, since that is what I need in this case?

Comment: No, you get to use double quotes for that bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this might do what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat .gitignore | while read line
do
    if [[ $line == *#* ]]
    then
        echo #skip
    else
        git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch '"$line" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
    fi
done
```

I avoided all the pointless intermediate variables that just complicated things. (Though just removing the single quote from `str1` and dropping `str2` might have been enough this is saner as far as I'm concerned.)

The filter just needs to be a single string but how you construct that string is up to you.

You can probably also collect all the patterns from gitignore and just run filter-branch once (and not need `--force` at that point) too.

```
#!/bin/bash

patts=()
while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line != *#* ]]; then
        patts+=("$line")
    fi
done < .gitignore

git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch '"${patts[*]}" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Also note that you should probably be sure that you are only dealing with simple patterns here because the `rm` and `.gitignore` understanding of patterns isn't quite the same in all cases I don't think.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks again. I started out writing without the extra string variables, but having not used bash scripting much, I was confused as to how to get $line in where I needed it. This solution was much simpler and helpful.